# Cocoa: Loading a XML File (array);

Tags: xml, arrays, cocoa, macos

Is there a way that I can load a XML File and put its data into an array for exemple:

The XML File:

```
<xml ...>
<adressbook>
    <contact name="Name" phone="00000000"/>
    <contact name="Name2" phone="00000002"/>
    <contact name="Name3" phone="00000003"/>
    <contact name="Name4" phone="00000004"/>
</adressbook>
```

Now what I have to to if I want each attribute in one array lets say:

NSArray* name;
NSArray* phone;

I want basically to make each array holds (consecutively) the XML Attributes. In this case it would be like:

name would hold:

Name
Name2
Name3
Name4

And phone:
00000000
000000002
000000003
000000004

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source:

```
NSXMLDocument* doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/folder/with/sample.xml"] options:0 error:NULL];

NSMutableArray* objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
NSMutableArray* descriptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];

NSXMLElement* root  = [doc rootElement];
NSArray* objectElements = [root nodesForXPath:@"//object" error:nil];
for(NSXMLElement* xmlElement in objectElements)
    [objects addObject:[xmlElement stringValue]];

NSArray* descElements = [root nodesForXPath:@"//description" error:nil];
for(NSXMLElement* xmlElement in descElements)
    [descriptions addObject:[xmlElement stringValue]];

NSLog(@"%@", objects);
NSLog(@"%@", descriptions);

[doc release];
[objects release];
[descriptions release];
```

Sample XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item id="0">
<object>First Object</object>
<description>Description One</description>
</item>
<item id="1">
<object>Second Object</object>
<description>Description Two</description>
</item>
</items>
```

Comment: Do you know how can I fix the [NSXMLDocument initWithData:options:error:]: nil argument because the initWithXMLString also returned this error on gdb and then the initWithData did too.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to have a look at my blog entry below about simplified xml

http://www.memention.com/blog/2009/10/31/The-XML-Runner.html

The code is available at github

https://github.com/epatel/EPXMLParsers

Ben Sgro supplied a fix for handling attributes.